# Using Dropbox without installation from PC lab?

Tags: dropbox

Is it possible to use Drop Box without installing it to a computer, for instance to use it from PC lab computers where installing software is not permitted?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, just go to [dropbox.com](http://dropbox.com) and login via the web interface.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe [DropboxPortableAHK](http://nionsoftware.com/dbpahk/) could help you?

> DropboxPortableAHK is a portable version of dropbox, it is based on the AutoHotkey language.